# Swift keeps throwing errors, can't find out why

Tags: swift, breakpoints, fatal-error

My swift app keeps throwing some fatal errors:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

The only problem is I can't seem to find out what line of code causes this error. Is there a way to see the line of code that is causing this error?

The project is too big to upload here so this is like the only thing I can do.

Best regards,
Luca Panjer

Comment: Maybe try to restart your xcode. That being said, avoid unsafe unwrapping. Always use `if let myVar = myVar { .. }` or `myVar?.myProp`.

Comment: Thanks, but I already tried that. @tskulbru

Comment: @PhillipMills A crash (EXC_BAD_ACCESS) isn't an exception.

Comment: Are you using this code in a playground or a full-on project?

Comment: @JoshuaNozzi It's a full-on project.

Comment: @PhillipMills This doesn't work either.

Comment: Updated my answer: Try restarting your Mac, not just Xcode.

Answer (score 2):

Xcode should halt the application and display the offending line in the editor with an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error. The comment about restarting Xcode is probably the best first troubleshooting step, as this behavior should occur whether or not you set an exception breakpoint (because this is a fatal, crashing error, not an exception). You may also try restarting your Mac entirely. I've had situations where Xcode just didn't behave properly until I completely restarted my Mac.

Comment: I will try restarting my macbook. Xcode does provide me with a line, it's this one:

0x1002a476c <+44>:  brk    #0x1

Comment: Seems like Xcode is having a bad day. The UI doesn't seem to be reflecting the information it's getting. If a Mac restart doesn't help, some other suggestions would be 1) Clean, then rebuild your project and try again (using the Clean command); and 2) reinstall Xcode (pain in the ass but may be necessary).

Comment: I just restared my macbook, it doesnt help. I will clean it.
EDIT: Cleaning doesn't help either. I am reinstalling xCode at the moment.

Comment: If none of the above helps, you really will need to post your project somewhere (Dropbox or some other file sharing site). It can't be *that* big...

Comment: I send you my Skype via your website. Could you please add me so we can talk there? I would like to send the project that way.

Comment: The time I volunteer on StackOverflow is meant to benefit everyone. I don't offer one-on-one help. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting this error...

```
unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

...then somewhere in your code you are force-unwrapping an `Optional` value using `!`. There is almost no other reason why this error message would be presented.

One common cause of this error is an `@IBOutlet` that is declared with a `!` but is not correctly connected in Interface Builder. I would disconnect and then re-connect all of the `@IBOutlet`s in your project just to make sure that they are connected correctly.

Other than that, go through every line of code where you use a `!` to force-unwrap something and either unwrap it manually using `if let` or `guard let`, or at least set a breakpoint so that you can narrow down which force-unwrapped optional is causing the error.

There's a reason why the `!` is sometimes referred to as a "bang!" It causes things to explode. And headaches. Lots of headaches.

Comment: Not necessarily ... it could be due to referencing an outlet that hasn't been connected yet. No "!" required.

Comment: An Outlet that hasn't been connected yet is an Optional that almost always has a !. As in `@IBOutlet var label: UILabel!`. In fact, it has to be marked with either a ? or ! because it is not initialized at the time it is declared. If it was marked with ? you would have to explicitly unwrap it and the compiler would not unexpectedly find nil (unless you force unwrapped it later with !)

Comment: Fair enough. My mistake.